# Separating NotifyIcon_Click and ItemMenu_Click events

Tags: c#, events, taskbar, notifyicon

I have an application which runs mostly within the taskbar, and its icon may be left clicked in order to open a Windows form.
The NotifyIcon also has a few MenuItems which can be accessed by right clicking, and each have their own click events to serve their functionality.

```
private void menuItem4_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (programEnabled == false)
    {
        programEnabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Enabled!");
    }
    else
    {
        programEnabled = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Disabled!");
    }
}

//Icon clicked!
private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Reopen the form
    Form f = new TemperForm();

}
```

Every time a MenuItem click event is activated however, NotifyIcon_Click also runs and I need that event for opening the Windows form. I don't want every time I click any MenuItem to also run the code that I wish to run when the icon is clicked.

How can I still use the NotifyIcon_Click event while not having it run every time I click a MenuItem?
I've been at this for hours and it's driving me up the wall!

Comment: I think it would be useful to see which events you are subscribing too with these event handlers in your code

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of events, how would I use this to change the event so that it only runs when a condition is met such as when the menu is not open?

Comment: The MouseClick event handler is not accurate, its second parameter is *MouseEventArgs*.  Now it becomes easy to check the e.Button property.

Comment: I've corrected this, but unfortunately checking what button is pressed won't help in this case. I want to be able to left click the icon to open the form, and left click options to select them. I need another way to differentiate whether the user clicked on the icon or a menu item

Comment: I have to be doing this wrong, I can't imagine everyone goes through this trouble since it seems like it should be such an easy thing to do. I don't understand why NotifyIcon_Click would even run when a menu option was clicked in the first place

Comment: @Lemniscate you could check who the sender of the event was.. Again I'm not fully sure where you attaching this event handlers to so its hard to say. The point of events is the the event raiser doesn't care who is listening, so you can't configure when the event is raised, all you can do is handle it and decide what to do. Like I started with, try check what/who the sender is I'm guessing if a menu item is clicked, it will a menu item object and if that is the case, don't open the form or vice versa, if you can check that it is the task bar icon then only open it if thats true